# drag and drop movie divs around a page

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, movie

I need to rework a project that relied on hover effect, quite nice, but not appropriate for the client. My task is to be able to choose an image and move it to an area in the screen (call it a movie screen) and then to have them play with an event like a play button.

I don't seriously expect any response other than perhaps to be pointed to some examples that utilize the moving of an object such as a movie file rather than a static image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look at [jQuery UI drag and drop demos](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

Once you've set it up, you could trigger the draggable image div to start playing a movie file once you've dropped it into a certain drop target, for example.

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({ drop: function(event, ui) { <call javascript to play movie here> }});
```